# How to deploy meteor 1.5 application using mup?

Tags: meteor, digital-ocean, meteor-up, mup

I had to update my Meteor application as accounts-facebook was not wokring on previous version which was Meteor 1.3. After running "meteor update" command the meteor version is now updated to 1.5. Previously I was using mupx to deploy my application on Digital Ocean but it is not working for Meteor 1.5.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: @DavidG Everytime I try to deploy it gives the following error:
/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:82
const unicodeNormalizePath = (path) => {
                                     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

Comment: The error hints to a "–" wrongfully being in the code. Post the code that this error message refers to.

Comment: @DavidG This error is encountered when the verification of deployment fails after I deploy using mupx.

Comment: Yes. Go to this location: `/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:82` and check for errors, especially an unwanted "–" being in the code.

Comment: @DavidG I don't think there is any unwanted "- " in the but I think the error is due to the node version as the file which is shown in the error uses ES6 syntax .